# "Object is possibly undefined" error even after check

Tags: typescript, strict

I get the error when accessing the `length` property. I understand that I could solve the problem by only retrieving the object once, and then performing the `undefined`-check. Or simply add a `!`. But I want to understand why this is happening, and find out if there is a nicer solution. Here is the contrived example:

```
type MyMap<K extends string> = { [key in K]: string|undefined }

const getValueLength = (tmp:MyMap<string>, key:string) => {
  return tmp[key] !== undefined && tmp[key].length
}
```

I'm running typescript 3.3 in strict mode.

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610779/typescript-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined-even-after-undefined-c) where the problem was that a check was made inside another function, that is not the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the key is seen as a function call, which could potentially mutate the object/value you're looking at, therefore there is no guarantee that the first and second calls of `tmp[key]` are finding the same thing.

To avoid this, make sure you're only calling it once:

```
type MyMap<K extends string> = { [key in K]: string | undefined };

const getValueLength = (tmp: MyMap<string>, key: string) => {
  const str = tmp[key];
  return str !== undefined && str.length;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know where I can learn more on why object property accessing is interpreted as a function call? I'm trying to understand the problem in a deeper way.

Comment: @pgsandstrom: Look at getters and setters, they allow you to define a `get` function that will be called when you try to access the property on an object.  You could implement a `get` function that returns an array on the first call and `undefined` on the second call, which would then make your original code fail as `tmp[key]` would have two different values in the same expression.